# How to enable parallel PDF export in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, parallel-processing, elisp, org-mode, emacs24

Recently I start to write a long article using org-mode. My article contains pounds of images, tables and code. So when I import my org file to pdf, the emacs will freeze for more than one minute to produce the pdf file. However in my opinion, I would like to continue to write or correct my article during the exporting.

So here is the question, can emacs parallelly process the exports with multiple thread or multiple processors?

Comment: Emacs is single-threaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can, it's emacs!

`(info "(org) The export dispatcher")`

> ‘C-a’
>        Toggle asynchronous export.  Asynchronous export uses an external
>        Emacs process that is configured with a specified initialization
>        file.
>
> ```
>  While exporting asynchronously, the output is not displayed.  It is
>  stored in a list called “the export stack”, and can be viewed from
>  there.  The stack can be reached by calling the dispatcher with a
>  double ‘C-u’ prefix argument, or with ‘&’ key from the dispatcher.
>
>  To make this behavior the default, customize the variable
>  ‘org-export-in-background’.
> ```

So, you can export asynchronously to PDF like this: <kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is wonderful. But it does not work in my situation. I bond the keybinding F3 with `(global-set-key [f3] 'org-latex-export-to-pdf)`, when press F3, the issue still exists, although i altered the default value of that command.

Comment: @user3173715, what if you use something like `(global-set-key [f3] (lambda () (interactive) (org-latex-export-to-pdf t)))`? (The `t` is the `ASYNC` option).